# Why does StackOverflow allow frivolous edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I see on almost every post that as soon as a question is posted there are individuals who jump in with very frivolous edits. This looks like a way to get more points and medals. The edits on formatting may make sense but a spacing here or a comma there or a newline somewhere or just replacing words with synonyms is a waste.

This often leads to conflicts of edits and the author may have no choice but to accept the edit. There is no way to reject a suggestion.

EDIT: To clarify, in the SO (not meta) questions are struck down for being duplicates or related. Posts are closed to stop 'me too', and repeat answers and comments. So it led me to believe that the platform cares for value add to the question and the answer. If the question is "What is 1 + 1" and the answer is "2" and the edits are made for changing 2 to two, I wasn't sure it adhered to that guideline.

That is the reason I came to the meta section and posted a discussion to understand the intent, discover features I may not know (example: I could rollback), get feedback from others (for ex: editing is not merely for points).

*Much like most responders felt strongly about edits no matter how trivial, a discussion should be welcome no matter how one may not like an opinion expressed, of course so long as there is no personal abuse/disrespect.*

Comment: You can only get editing badges once, and you don't get reputation for edits after ~500 edits or if you have 2k+ total rep.  But maybe some of these edits *are* trivial; got any specific examples?

Comment: I think the UX on that was confusing. First up @Makoto the example in the link above by Hans is one where unnecessary word edits were made and that ended up conflicting my own edit thereby removing actually useful edit that was addressing the question.

So @HansPassant - wrt the UX it seemed to tell me that the edit was suggested and the only action that was shown to me was `Approve`. This was odd. I didn't see `Reject` as an option.

Comment: Perhaps the edit was already rejected by the time you saw it (for example, editing it yourself will auto-reject any pending edits). In that case it will give the author the ability to still approve the edit, but not reject since it is already rejected. There should be a notice on the review in that case, though.

Comment: Sorry @perennial_noob, not seeing the comment you're referencing.

Comment: Don't forget that anybody under 2k/500 edits requires approval in the suggested edits review queue. Beyond that, if somebody makes a non-vandalizing edit, it's generally ok because the only one benefiting from it is the post itself.

Comment: [The edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22545190) that presumably started this. The UI should have offered a variety of options, including various forms of rejection and approval. In any case, I would not characterize the edit in question as "trivial"; it removed content that I would consider *significant* from your answer. So this is not a problem of some trivial or "frivolous" edit; it's a wrong edit, and the UI either broke or confused you.

Comment: Yeah and there was no way for me to flag that review. But even beyond this example I have seen others where people make tiny edits by adding `,` or an extra ` `. Those are trivial.
@NicolBolas - actually the edit was not wrong in that it didn't attempt to remove the lines because I hadn't posted my edit yet. So that significant part that got removed was because of an edit conflict which I was forced to accept. I hope that helped clarify.

Comment: That 5 minutes edits-with-no-history ability for authors of the post mess edits all the time... Indeed it is rarely problem for good questions as OP re-read and edited they text multiple times while preparing the post over week or two.

Comment: It seems like there is an agreement over how unnecessary and painful these are. Should this be a feature request tag then?
That is: Provide an ability to reject edits or disable edits of certain formats?

Comment: @perennial_noob It's already possible to reject edits, but in your case it wasn't because _it was already rejected_. If you look at [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22545190) you can see that it already was rejected automatically by the Community user due to your previous (conflicting) edit. You as the post owner have the ability to overrule that decision which is what you did by approving it. You could've just ignored the suggestion.

Comment: Darn it! So I misunderstood it then. It was confusing. I thought `approve` meant to approve my change overriding the edit suggestion.

Here is a new one. This is what boils my blood. It actually overwrote an important edit I was already making. I want to report this edit - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55309348/revisions

Comment: The problem seems to be that you post something with intentions of continuing to edit it. That's not really the way it's supposed to work. How am I, as a potential editor, supposed to know that I need to wait longer for you to get your posted edited into shape before I fix grammar and formatting issues? If you plan to post as quickly as possible, *then* edit, you're bound to run into editor conflicts.

Comment: Are grammatical corrections and formatting issues that critical? It looks like a way to be a quick draw on edits by others is to keep a keen eye on the rolling stream of new questions and look to 'edit' formats and grammatical errors. In the recent link, the editor changed the capitalization in a bullet list. It was not even a paragraph. How are these edits important. They are meaningless fluff adding no value to the question nor the answer. For a platform that insists on answers adding value these edits are useless.

Comment: @perennial_noob: "*I want to report this edit -*" There's nothing to report. The user in question has earned the right to edit posts without review. Now yes, their edit was bad, but *only because* it removed information from your answer. But you fixed that by rolling it back. The capitalization and formatting fixes? Those were perfectly valid uses of his editing privileges.

Comment: @perennial_noob: Or let me put it another way. We don't want people editing posts in a way that changes the *intent* of the post. Fixing formatting (using an actual Markdown numeric list when that's clearly what you were trying to do, for example) and correcting grammar are *exactly* the kinds of things that edits should be doing. Take those away, and there's pretty much no reason to allow *anyone* to edit posts other than their own.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I am for edits! But I guess my point is that in the zeal (my guess to earn points or visibility or not sure what) editors jump onto it in a matter of seconds/minutes. There perhaps isn't a trivial way to identify how trivial the edits are. SO has a worldwide presence. And surely everyone doesn't have the same way of expressing themselves. In general, if the question/answer made sense, then `,`, or markdowns can wait.
Also, how can we claim that the edit preserves the intent? Or how is "Will not" to "Won't", for ex, necessary?
I appreciate everyone's patience in this discussion!

Comment: @perennial_noob: "*if the question/answer made sense, then `,`, or markdowns can wait.*" Wait for what, exactly? How is the post improved by waiting to improve it? "*how can we claim that the edit preserves the intent?*" Formatting and presentation is not intent.

Comment: I have an example of what I consider to be a frivolous edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26051659 The only change was to remove a small amount of whitespace (e.g. change my indent from 4 spaces to 2 and remove a space from "if (" to "if(" and similar. This seems like a frivolous edit to me.
As per the answer, below, it is difficult for me to see how removing 8-10 space characters from a post as the only change "substantially improves the post" and yet it was accepted by 2 other users on my behalf!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ignoring the initial impetus for this question (which was caused by a confusion between the user and the UX in an oddball situation), let's address the main thrust of it.

We explicitly do not allow users whose edits have to be reviewed (those with less than 2K rep) to make extremely small edits (less than 6 characters). And we encourage reviewers to reject edits which do not substantially improve the post, typically by fixing most if not all of the problems in it.

But once your edits don't have to be reviewed, you're basically on the honor system. If you have 2K rep, you're expected to know what we expect of editors. The OP of a post does have a greater degree of control, since they're notified of edits to their posts, can cast binding review votes to edits to their posts, and can always roll them back even if they have less than 2K rep. But other than that, they're simply another user.

[The point of allowing users to edit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) is to improve the *presentation* of content on the site. We specifically don't want people editing posts in a way that changes their intent. Yes, you can add text, embellish things, maybe explain a point a bit better, but we don't really encourage adding genuinely new content to a post.

As such, most edits are *supposed* to be grammatical and formatting related. We allow people to edit for the primary purpose of letting them improve the presentation of content.

> my guess to earn points or visibility or not sure what

Once you have [edit-anywhere privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), you no longer earn reputation for making edits. And, as previously stated, excessively trivial edit suggestions tend to be rejected.

So the reason why these edits were made is obvious: the user thinks the post is better that way.

Comment: Btw, the post was tagged `discussion`. And I see it is received negatively. So am I to understand that asking questions or understanding intent behind features is a no-no? I am referring to the negative votes on the question itself.

Comment: @perennial_noob: "*So am I to understand that asking questions or understanding intent behind features is a no-no?*" You could also assume that it's something about how you phrased the question. Part of what you talk about isn't true (the whole "no choice but to accept"). There's also the way you denigrate formatting changes as "a waste", which is something not a lot of people agree on. Your post is not merely asking a question; it's taking sides. So are the people voting on that question in part based on which side they prefer.

Comment: The point of a discussion is to express an opinion and seek feedback. If I don't stand for something, then what am I discussing? Denigrating is a heavy word because the 'waste' that I referred to was in what seemed like lost changes which you and I recognized as a glitch and/or a UX quirk.

It is not your fault that the question got negative votes so I am not pointing fingers. But just like edits are okay no matter how trivial, opinions in discussions are okay no matter how passionate.
You & I can't control the votes but I definitely can refute the concerns regarding phrasing, denigrating.

Comment: FWIW, in my OP I was clear when I said 'it looks like'. It was to seek affirmation or negation which is what the answers are for. It is in the comments that we are further discussing intricacies and so the question itself had no tone of disrespect.

Comment: @perennial_noob: I would disagree with the "no tone of disrespect" assertion. Saying "This looks like" doesn't stop it from reading as an accusation IMO, *especially* when the previous sentence talks about "there are individuals who jump in with very frivolous edits". That "frivolous" isn't exactly assuming good intent, is it? There are plenty of times where *minor* edits can still be positive, including adding or removing line breaks. Calling those edits frivolous is *not* respectful IMO.

Comment: @perennial_noob where are you getting *stopped* from asking questions? You say you are allowed to stand for something? **Absolutely**. Does it mean I can't disagree? And on meta, someone disagreeing with your premise will likely downvote. The voting culture is different. No one is saying you shouldn't ask. People are just telling you they disagree with you. That's it.

Answer (score 13):

As someone who readily edits other people's posts as soon as they're posted, I'd like to defend the practice.

If I see small changes that can be made to a post to make it easier to understand, I'll edit them in if I have the patience (which is fairly often). Many new users don't properly format their code, and introduce syntactic and grammatical errors that make their question harder to read. I enjoy minor editorial work, and salvaging otherwise good questions is beneficial for the site, so, why not? Worst case scenario, I waste my own time (which isn't really your concern). Best case scenario, I help improve the chances that the OP will get an answer.

And I'll note, in roughly *10* edits, I'll have the Copy Editor badge that you're referring to. That will be the only reward I'll have ever gotten from editing posts, and I'll only ever get it once. I edit posts because I enjoy improving questions, not because I'm after some rep or badges.

Answer (score 4):

Because they are generally improving the posts.

Even tiny improvements, will increase the chance of questions get better answers, and answers better helping OPs and future readers.
Not all users on StackOverflow have good English skills and reading skills, format and editorial improvements will help everyone understand the posts better, and save people's time.

> see on almost every post that as soon as a question is posted there are individuals who jump in with very frivolous edits.

Many times it is like that. However the edits, although might be tiny, are improvements most of the times. OPs, especially *New contributor*s often don't post and format well, leave room for improvement. On the other hand, you can see those posts by senior members, leave little room for improvement, thus seldom (but not never) edited by others.

> This looks like a way to get more points and medals.

There are only one or two *frivolous* badges for edits, and at most [1000 reps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) for users under 2k reptuation. There's no reputation gain for users above 2k reps to edit posts. Some users maybe edit posts for the points and badges, but that's only partial, and many more high-rep users who already got the badges long ago are still helping improving posts.
The point of the awards, is to encourage people to edit -- it's generally a good thing for everybody.

> The edits on formatting may make sense but a spacing here or a comma there or a newline somewhere or just replacing words with synonyms is a waste.

Nope, it's not a waste. Small improvements, are still improvements. And we can actually learn from those edits. I believe many people, like myself, improved English and editorial skills through others' edits.

> This often leads to conflicts of edits and the author may have no choice but to accept the edit. There is no way to reject a suggestion.

You have choice, and there is way to reject.
If the edit is proposed by users under 2k rep, then you can choose to accept or reject or further improve. (Reviewers might dealt with the suggestion before you, but you still have the final saying. However I suggest you check the edit first, if it's a good edit then don't just refuse or revert, instead improve base on it)
If it is made by users above 2k rep, then it is a edit not a suggestion, so you can not *reject* it, but you can click the ***edited some times ago*** link to check the revisions and choose to rollback or edit base on any revision.
There is the possibility, though tiny, of certain high-rep user keep editing the post against your will, vandalizing the post. In such case, you can flag the post to notify the moderators come to help you.